# matlab - plot square matrix by row

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

Plot uses columns to plot a square matrix, but I need it by rows.

`plot(matrix(1:end,1:end), 1:columns)`

works great when matrix is rectangular (plots each line of matrix with a different color), but when matrix is square is plots by column (as the documentation clearly states)
I don't want to break the command to a loop because then I will have to specify the color for each line plot.

Is there a way to change the plot defaults to prefer row in square matrices?

Comment: how about transposing and plotting? wont it work? `plot(matrix.', 1:columns)`

Comment: good call, thanks. I was hoping for something I wouldn't have to explain in the code, so I can call it 'self-documented'...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trick and add a line of `NaN` at the end of the array:

```
matrix(end+1,:) = NaN;
```

And now `matrix` is rectangular, but the `NaN` won't be displayed during plot.

Best,